# java iterating through index +1 and -1 for image errosion model

Tags: java, pixel

I have been given the task of writing a script to "erode" a binary image i.e. black and white photo.

This means that I must distinguish the parts that are white from black, where on an RGB scale, black is 0 and 1 is white.

Pixels are iterated over on a horizontal (`i` index) and vertical (`j` index). In order for a pixel to be considered a particular colour, it's immediate neighbours must be of that colour i.e. `i+1` and `i-1` and `j+1` and `j-1`.

My attempt to code this is as follows:

```
public static BufferedImage getErodedImage(BufferedImage image) {
    BufferedImage target = copyImage(image);
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getRaster().getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getRaster().getHeight(); j++) {
            if (i + 1)||(i - 1) == 0 {
                i = 0
            }
            else{
                i = 1
            }

        }
        if (j + 1)||(j - 1) == 0 {
            j = 0
        }
        else{
            j = 1
        }
    }
}
```

My attempt is very pythonic and returns lots of Errors and I'm guessing that I might need another for loop to iterate the -1, 0 and +1 values. and then set the value of the i-th pixel.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

In your code a lot of syntax error, try to use this code:

```
public static BufferedImage getErodedImage(BufferedImage image) {
    BufferedImage target = copyImage(image);
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getRaster().getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getRaster().getHeight(); j++) {
            if (i + 1 == 0 || i - 1 == 0) { // not  if (i + 1)||(i - 1) == 0
                i = 0; // ;
            }
            else{
                i = 1; // ;
            }
            if (j + 1 == 0 ||j - 1 == 0) { // not if (j + 1)||(j - 1) == 0 and this "if" should be in "for (int j..." 
                j = 0; // ;
            }
            else{
                j = 1; // ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do realize that this will (in most cases) end up as an infinite loop? It'll keep setting `i` and `j` to either `0` or `1` no matter what...